# Is it possible to kill SSH connections that aren't running a command (e.g. with -N)

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

If a client does not execute a command (e.g. with -N) within some timeframe (1-2 seconds) after establishing the SSH connection, I'd like to terminate it from the server.

Unfortunately, `ForceCommand` and `authorized_keys`-prefixed commands do not execute either when run with `-N`, but clients could still conceivably request remote forwards (`-R`) tying up ports on your server.

I'd like to prevent this scenario but prefixing the keys with `no-port-forwarding` isn't an option because **if** they run a command I want to allow port forwarding. In this case my forced command executes and I can do validation to ensure that it is allowed.

Is my only option having some external process monitor `sshd` instances and check if they have any child processes (e.g. shell or executed command)?

Comment: Did you manage to get this to wotk?

Comment: @PauloArruda not to my recollection. I experimented with a monitor of sorts and then lost interest in the project. Sorry :(

Comment: I solved it on my website [Burrow.io](https://burrow.io) using shell scripts.

Comment: @PauloArruda nice. Do you want to add an answer that describes what you're doing maybe with some critical code snippets. I'll accept it as the answer for the question if you do.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that `-N` works always, then there is no other option besides having external process monitor the childs of sshd. I have checked the man page for sshd_config and didn't find any option which would help you. Also it doesn't specify if `-N` should work with `ForceCommand` or not.